# What did I do wrong when I installed this theme?

Tags: themes, gtk

I have a problem installing a theme for my Ubuntu, note that I am very new to it and probably messed something up. Still it seems to me that I did everything like it was stated in the INSTALL file.

Theme: http://opendesktop.org/content/show.php/?content=140562

So I downloaded the *.zip package, unzipped it in `~/.themes` folder and changed Controls and Borders inside my theme preference. Still my result is pretty poor. You can look at the image, it looks nothing like what in the screenshot of the author. I also installed fonts running `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` and tried to install GTK2 engine as `sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine gtk2-engines-pixbuf`, but it showed that 0 files was modified since I already have it.

Please tell me what did I did wrong so I can fix that :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uh... The theme is for Gnome. You, as per your screenshot, are clearly using Unity. Unity is Canonical's replacement for the Gnome desktop environment. Think of them as something like Explorer on windows (not just the file browser, but the Explorer bar as well). You're running an entirely different interface than the one that skin was made for.

Sadly, installing Gnome 3 in Ubuntu is painful and unpleasant, and unless you are lucky, it won't end without problems. Furthermore, despite the final release state of Gnome 3, it really comes off as Alpha software in is buggyness, missing features, and lack of options -- whereas Unity is, at least, beta software. I'd link you to help installing Gnome 3, but after following 3 or 4 different guides myself, I ended up with a frankenstein's monster of an install. Would not recommend. Try switching from Ubuntu to a distro that comes with Gnome 3 prepacked, if you really want to -- like Fedora, for example.

Comment: Ah, no it's not worth it. :) But how do I know which themes will run on my Ubuntu and which will not?

Comment: Well, this one was clear enough: it said "Gnome Shell" and "GTK2" and "GTK3" a whole lot. This is not what you have. If it says that it is a theme for Unity, it will work for you. Also, if it specifically mentions Ubuntu 11.04 or later, it is likely going to work for you, as Ubuntu, starting with 11.04, runs Unity, and not Gnome -- which is, naturally, why you have it.

Comment: My point of contention in this case is that my understanding is such that Unity does in fact run on top of Gnome.  Have I misunderstood this?

Answer (score 0):

Without having tried this myself, my only comment would be that this theme is designed around Gnome 3.0.* and the r69 version of the Unico engine.  Perhaps there is some slight incompatibility between the theme and GTK2.

Comment: There are both GTK+3 and GTK+2 versions.

Comment: I had seen this, but because it was noted that this theme was originally designed for Gnome 3.0, I was suggesting the possibility that perhaps there were incompatibilities associated with using it with GKT2.  Since I have not given this theme a shot, I am unable to say for certain.

Comment: It doesn't really matter which version of Gnome it's for, seeing as he is clearly running Unity. =/

Answer (score 0):

[This post on Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/zukitwo-beautiful-gnome23shell-theme.html) would help. I'm quite sure that somehow you are using the Zukitwo Dark variation.